# Remove key/value pairs with the same value (i.e. duplicates) in an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, keyvaluepair

I'm currently learning JS and I need a way to return an object that is similar to the given object but removing key/value pairs that have the same value (i.e. duplicates).

So if I had a given object { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1 }:

it should return:

{b: 2, c: 3 }

Similarly, if all key-value pairs in an object had different values, the returned object would simply be the same as the given object.

I think I am close to solving it but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
const noDuplicateValues = (obj) => {
  let result = {};
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  let duplicate;

  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i +1; j < keys.length; j++) {
      duplicate = false;
      if(obj[keys[i]] === obj[keys[j]]) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate) {
      result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    } 
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: why it should remove `a` and `d`

Comment: I'm doing an exercise that asks me to return an object that removes key-value pairs with the same value. Since a and d both have the value of 1, it will be removed from the returned object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed things up, your inner loop can exit as soon as it finds a duplicate. But the flaw which is preventing it from working correctly is that while it finds that `a` is a duplicate of `d` and correctly omits `a`, it doesn't omit `d` because when it checks `d`, which is the last element in the array, there are no subsequent elements to compare against, so it doesn't consider `d` to be a duplicate.

The fix is to make the inner loop check *every* element (not just the ones after the one being checked by the outer loop), of course being careful not to check an element against itself:

```
const noDuplicateValues = (obj) => {
    let result = {};
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let duplicate;

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        duplicate = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            if (
                i !== j // Don't compare an element with itself
                &&
                obj[keys[i]] === obj[keys[j]]
            ) {
                duplicate = true;
                break; // Found a dupe so we can stop checking this one for dupes
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var x = noDuplicateValues({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1 });
console.log(x); // Object { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd count up the number of occurrences of each value, then filter the object's entries by whether a given entry's value only occurs once:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1 };
const occurrences = new Map();
for (const val of Object.values(obj)) {
  occurrences.set(val, (occurrences.get(val) || 0) + 1);
}
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([, val]) => occurrences.get(val) === 1)
);
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.
First one is that the value of `duplicate` is set to `false` in the inner loop, it should be set in the outer loop instead.
The secone issue is the inner loop only starts from `i + 1`. Therefore it actually does the following comparison:

- `a` vs `b`, `a` vs `c`, `a` vs `d`
- `b` vs `c`, `b` vs `d`
- `c` vs `d`

So what you also need is to compare value of `d` vs `a`, `b`, `c` as well. So something like this should hopefully work.

```
const noDuplicateValues = (obj) => {
  let result = {};
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  let duplicate;

  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
    duplicate = false;
    for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      
      if(i !== j && obj[keys[i]] === obj[keys[j]]) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate) {
      result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    } 
  }
  return result;
}
```

But it would be more efficient if you just keep track of the value and the number of occurrence: 1 : occur 2 times , 2 : 1 time, 3 : 1 time ...
Then you can remove all the key-value pairs whose the value occur more than 1 time. This way you only need to loop through all the properties once.